# How To Resolve Apple APNS Error BadDeviceToken

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mobile-application

To setup my existing app with push notifications, recently I've created the KEY in apple developer. I've also provided the APNS file, team id and key id. When I try to send a message, I'm getting BadDeviceToken error. What should be done to get push notifications to work on an Apple app?

Comment: may be there is conflict between development and production token... while testing make sure to use sandbox=true

Comment: If I'm planning to test it out on TestFlight, is there anything to note? Example signing certificate, production token etc..